# IIS delegation to access network resources with Kerberos

Tags: iis, kerberos, delegation

I have a ASP.NET application that need to access to ANOTHER application, the ANOTHER application expecting Kerberos authentication, it based on the user credential to response to the request. My ASP.NET app is running on a AD service account that is setup to allow delegate to the ANOTHER application (with proper SPN).

So the process is, user requests to the ASP.NET app, the ASP.NET app will impersonate the request to the ANOTHER application by delegation (with kerberos).

When I run the app in local machine (My ASP.NET resides), the request was successful, however, if the request is coming from remote client machine, it failed, from the ANOTHER application's log, it shows the Identity is not presented.
Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following which appears to be very similar to your situation:

https://serverfault.com/questions/270293/moving-my-website-to-different-server-changes-authentication-from-kerberos-to-ntl/270306#270306

There are some resources that that should help you troubleshoot.